# hadoop Ingest files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, ingest

i am very new to hadoop ask for your help.
I'm doing the process of digesting files from one directory to another. The following comand that I use:

> Blockquote
>   hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ./tmp/text.txt ./tmp/harSourceFolder2

but the results always fail. the following results:

> Blockquote
>   2020-02-08 14:53:42,448 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   copyFromLocal: `./tmp/harSourceFolder2': No such file or directory:`hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser1/tmp/harSourceFolder2'

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are doing an assing to a file and not to a directory. To make it works you have to assign the `/` character. `Blockquote hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ./tmp/text.txt ./tmp/harSourceFolder2/`